# Redirect old page to new page HTML

Tags: html, html-lists

Old website like this:
www.example.com/oldnews.html

oldnews.html page changed to now newnews.html

New website like this:
www.example.com/newnews.html

When type any one
www.example.com/oldnews.html
automatically page redirected to new page =>

www.example.com/newnews.html

How to page redirect old page to new page?

Use an .htaccess file?

Answer (score 10):

Try this for HTML5

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url='http://www.yourdomain.com/newindex.html'">
```

I see below it says "Use 301 redirects if you are willing to use server-side. Meta tags, as described in the other answer, are best for client-side."

Any redirect done in the code or on a server is called server-side. When we make a change in Firefox or Chrome or any browser that changes the way an end-user interacts with the web it is called client-side.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: that is wrong.
it has to be <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://www.yourdomain.com/newindex.html'">
documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Answer (score 2):

Use 301 redirects if you are willing to use server-side. Meta tags, as described in the other answer, are best for client-side.

Comment: www.example.com/oldnews.html page is not there.where will i write code redirect page?i have only this page www.example.com/newnews.html.